# Trying to turn continuous variable into categorical variable with unequal sizes

Tags: r

**I am trying to turn Failures_Avg from continuous into a factor of 3 levels.**

Use <- read_csv("FinalData.csv")%>% filter(Week %between% c("1", "7")) %>% dplyr::select(-c(LactationNumber,DaysPerWeek, TotalWeeks))%>%
mutate_at(vars(Farm,Parity,CowNr,Week,Failures_Avg), as.factor)%>%
mutate_at(vars(Milk_AvgDay,Milk_AvgVisit,IntervalCV), as.numeric)%>%
group_by(Farm,CowNr)

Here I read in failures_Avg as a categorical variable but since it is continuous there are about 65 levels. I am trying to change it from this into

Low - =0

Med - Between 0 & including 1

High - Greater than 1

**Thank you in advance**

Answer (score 2):

We can use `cut`

```
library(dplyr)
Use %>%
   mutate(failures_Avg = cut(failures_Avg, breaks = c(-Inf, 0, 1, Inf), labels = c("Low", "Med", "High")))
```

or `case_when`

```
Use <- Use %>%
     mutate(failures_Avg = case_when(failures_Avg == 0 ~ "Low",
                 (failures_Avg > 0 & failures_Avg < 1) ~ "Med",
                   TRUE ~ "High"))
```

Comment: will this have low being solely zero and med including 1 or will it be right below 1 and/or will this be including 0?

Comment: @Swart205 If you are using `dplyr::between`, it is a shortcut for `x >= left & x <= right` , but you can make this more specific, by changing it to `failures_Avg > 0 & failures_Avg < 1` in the code

Comment: Use <- read_csv("FinalData.csv")%>% filter(Week %between% c("1", "7")) %>% dplyr::select(-c(LactationNumber,DaysPerWeek, TotalWeeks))%>%
  mutate_at(vars(Farm,Parity,CowNr,Week,Failures_Avg), as.factor)%>%
  mutate_at(vars(Milk_AvgDay,Milk_AvgVisit,IntervalCV), as.numeric)%>%
    group_by(Farm,CowNr) %>% 
     mutate(Failures_Avg = case_when(Failures_Avg == 0 ~ "Low",
                   between(Failures_Avg, >0, <=1) ~ "Med",
                   TRUE ~ "High"))

Comment: I tried doing this and then received Error: unexpected ')' in "                   TRUE ~ "High")"

Comment: I meant to remove the `between` if use `(failures_Avg > 0 & failures_Avg < 1)  ~"Med",`

Comment: @Swart205 try the update one in my post